# Why does a User having access on a specific file share in a Azure storage account able to mount and access another file share as well?

Tags: azure, mount, azure-files, azure-storage-files, azure-file-share

I'm currently working on an Azure scenario that involves three AD users: A, B, and C. I have set up a Storage account with three File Shares: F1, F2, and F3.

My intention was to grant User A access to all three file shares, so I assigned the `"Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"` role to User A for all three file shares through Access Control.

For User B, I only granted access to the F2 file share, and for User C, I granted access solely to the F3 file share by assigning the `"Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"` role.

Here's the breakdown:

```
Username FileShare
User A - F1, F2, F3
User B - F2
User C - F3
```

Surprisingly, when I logged into the Azure Windows VM as User B and attempted to mount the drive for the file share using the Storage Account name as the username and the Access Key as the password, I was able to successfully mount all three file shares. This outcome is unexpected since I had only granted access to User B for the F2 file share.

Could someone kindly assist me in understanding what I might have missed or how I can implement the desired scenario?

Comment: Please see this: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview#use-the-storage-account-key-for-superuser-permissions.